# Yield keyword return 0x107e4b3c0 while Return function only returns Last value in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created a small program to output Name char along with position of char but it does not work as i expected.

Yield return nothing while Return statement returns only last values of both char and num lists.

```
name_letters = "Alexi Rodrigo"

def get_number():
    for number in xrange(1, len(name_letters)+1):
        yield number

def letters_list():
    for letter in name_letters:
         yield letter


print "                      "  
print "======================"
print " "+" "+"Text w/ Numbers"
print "======================"
print "                      " 


output_text =  get_number(), letters_list()

print output_text


## Output should be  Letter + Position Number
```

Comment: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Generators

Comment: @RolfofSaxony This site does not answer my question.

Comment: using `yield` creates a generator function, which is supposed to be used in loops. As for `return` it should return first values not last isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try following...

```
for n, c in enumerate(name_letters):
    print n, c
```

If you do not want space to be numbered

```
name_letters = "Alexi Rodrigo"

n = 0
for c in name_letters:
    if c != ' ':
        print n, c
        n += 1
    else:
        print c
```

Comment: This kinda works but why it print   5  for an empty space?

Comment: That's because empty space is also a character

Comment: Use `for n, c in enumerate(name_letters.replace(' ', ''):` if you do not want that. Please mark as accepted if it works.

Comment: I need that empty space but does want to count it.

Comment: You mean an empty line for the space without number ?

Comment: I want it like that way.

Comment: Thanks man. May i know why is that Return only return first value? Is there are no way to make Return statement to return all values?

Comment: You can also return list say `return name_numbers`

Comment: If you do not mind, Could you please check the code here https://pastebin.com/pxLcxW1D ?

Comment: Yeah I see that. You get the last char and number. As you are looping all list and returning whatever is left in the variables in last iteration.

Comment: Should I reformat that code as your code to make it works or is there are any way in my own style to make it works?

Comment: You can use `yield` as in your code. You must, however, understand how it works. I think SO is not the right place to explain. I am sure there are a lot of good sites with better examples.